# I am getting an error when using pokeApi in Angular http service

Tags: angular, rest, http

I searched on Internet and tried many times, but unfortunately I cannot get the data from the rest api.
I want to get the data and show the frontend first, then I'll do the detail mask, but I have trouble getting the first data.

I get different errors every time on console.

Thank you from now :)

***pokedex-service.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

 import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import { PokeAPI, PokemonDetails } from '../../shared/pokemon.model';

 @Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
 })
 export class PokedexService {
 private API_URL = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon ';

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 retrieveAll(): Promise<PokeAPI[]> {
 return this.http.get<PokeAPI[]>(this.API_URL).toPromise();
 }
 }
```

***pokemon.model.ts***

```
 export interface Results {
 name: string;
 url: string;
 id?: string;
 details?: PokemonDetails;
 description?: string;
 }

 export interface PokeAPI {
 count: number;
 next: string;
 results: Results[];
 }

 export interface PokemonDetails {
 name: string;
 id: number;
 sprites: Sprites;
 abilities?: Array<any>;
 types?: Array<any>;
 }

 export interface Sprites {
 front_default: string;
 }
```

***pokedex-list.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { PokeAPI, PokemonDetails, Results } from '../../shared/pokemon.model';
 import { PokedexService } from '../../shared/services/pokedex-service.service';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-pokedex-list',
 templateUrl: './pokedex-list.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./pokedex-list.component.scss'],
 })
 export class PokedexListComponent implements OnInit {
 pokemonList: PokeAPI[];

 constructor(private pokedexService: PokedexService) {}

 ngOnInit() {
 this.refresh();
 }

 refresh() {
 return this.pokedexService.retrieveAll().then((customerList) => {
 this.pokemonList = customerList;
 console.log(this.pokemonList);
 });
 }
 }
```

***pokedex-list.component.html***

```
<div class="album py-5 bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div
          class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"
          *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemons.results"
        >
          <svg
            class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top"
            width="100%"
            height="225"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
            focusable="false"
            role="img"
            aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"
          >
            <title>Placeholder</title>
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" />
            <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text>
          </svg>
          <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">
              {{ pokemon.name }}
            </p>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
              <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                  View
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
                  Edit
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running using ng serve you will not be able to access a server of different origin. As the angular dev server blocks the cross origin request. You can use a --proxy-config option in ng serve to solve this problem.